# C# Use Windows 7 control look in windows xp

Tags: c#, winforms

I found out how to do it in WPF but how can I achieve this in winforms?  The most important thing I want to use is the new calendar control but I would love to have the whole app be Windows 7-like.  Sorry if this has been answered already but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: No, that's not the answer. Those controls only have the "Aero" (Windows Vista/7) look under Windows Vista and 7. They won't look like that on Windows XP. They'll be themed in the Windows XP theme, which is called "Luna". There's no way of achieving what you want in WinForms. WinForms simply uses the native Windows controls, and the Aero theme is not available for controls in Windows XP. You'd have to completely owner-draw them, which you'd never get to look right. Stick with the user's current OS theme; it's what every other app on their system does, and it's by far the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native way to do it with WinForms. WPF is a "Exception" as it draws everything itself instead of through the system...

There are though a number of companies that sell themed controls. Such as...
https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/

This company also has a lot of controls including a calander:
http://www.bcgsoft.com/